# Eclipse 4.2 creating Windows carriage return on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I am currently experiencing this problem on newest Eclipse Release (4.2), with PDT (PHP Development Tools) installed. Even though the Preferences > General > Workspace is with "New text file line delimiter" set to "Unix", I am still getting the \n\r Windows format for every code I write...

Is anyone experiencing that problem, and how to solve it?

Right now, I am doing a workaround with dos2unix command from terminal, but it is pretty annoying as Eclipse is well equipped to handle this on its own.

Comment: Forcing the same configuration in the project level at: Properties > Resource, seems to be a workaround fix... still checking...

Comment: I had a similar issue, but only when pasting. As indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842597/copy-and-paste-in-eclipse-adds-window-newlines-at-the-end-of-each-pasted-line), the fix was to got to Preferences > PHP > Editor > Typing and turn off indentation adjustment when pasting.

Answer (score 1):

Are the newlines still wrong after you save a file again? After you reformat and save? Eclipse won't convert existing files when you change the Preferences.

You might need to convert everything manually with dos2unix to fix you existing files.

Comment: Java perspective looks fine though.